# Windows 7 not automatically detecting proxy settings; cannot connnect to the internet

Tags: networking, windows-7, proxy, connection

I just recently installed Windows 7 SP 1 on my computer.  However it failed, and I rolled back the installation, only to now have an error with my ethernet port, saying that I cannot connect, for the stated reason.

How can I fix this?  Without having to format my PC?

I have tried

- Resetting Winsock
- Flushing my DNS via ipconfig.
- Disabled/ Enabled my network adapter.

Comment: You need to tell us a little more about your network -- are you at home or at work? What do you know about your network connection outside your laptop? The Ethernet port is probably correct, but it cannot find a path to the wider world -- perhaps because of a local network configuration (like a proxy server you need to know about), or perhaps because of the Windows 7 security has been set up.

Comment: This is a home network.  I am running Windows 7 on my desktop computer.  I am posting this comment from my laptop.

Comment: This is a home network.  I am running Windows 7 on my desktop computer.  I am posting this comment from my laptop.  I have never had to do this before, as it was all automatically handled.  My router is a DGl-4300, and I just have a modem that comcast gave me.  I tried rolling back my update, but I get a strange hex error.  I know its an OS error, because my ethernet port works when I boot into ubuntu.  Is this enough information? **edit

Comment: Can you reinstall the ethernet drivers?

Comment: Can you please try resetting your IE settings on Tools - Internet option - Advanced - Reset settings?

Answer (score 1):

I tried doing so.  I uninstalled my ethernet drivers, I rebooted my machine, and still, I encountered the error.  I'm just gonna take my chances with guessing that SP 1 borked my machine, and so I am reinstalling windows.